# How do I set the default schema for a user in MySQL

Tags: mysql, default, database-schema

Is there a way to set a default schema for each user in MySQL and if so how?  Where user x would default to schema y and user z would default to schema a.

Comment: Are user `x` and `z` MySQL users, or users of some other system (e.g. your OS)?  Do you only need to specify a default database when using one type of client (e.g. mysql CLI, or PHP Data Objects), or do you need it to be for all clients?  Do you need/want to override any default schema specified by the client on connecting?  Do you want to disable changing of the default schema after one has been selected?

Comment: MySQL does not support schemas. Do you mean "database" instead?

Comment: Oracle MySQL refers to databases as schemas in their tools.  So where Microsoft has schemas and databases, MySQL just has schemas, but we call them databases.

Answer (score 91, accepted):

There is no default database for user. There is default database for current session.

You can get it using DATABASE() function -

```
SELECT DATABASE();
```

And you can set it using USE statement -

```
USE database1;
```

You should set it manually - `USE db_name`, or in the connection string.

Comment: Will that user now always have database1 as their default schema every time they log in, or you have to say USE database1; each time you connect?

Comment: You should set default database every time using `USE database` or connection string. The MySQL creates new session without default database.

Comment: Is it possible to utilize `USE` dynamically? Something like `USE (SELECT schema FROM blahblah WHERE blahblah)`

Answer (score 19):

If your user has a local folder e.g. Linux, in your users home folder you could create a .my.cnf file and provide the credentials to access the server there. for example:-

```
[client]
host=localhost
user=yourusername
password=yourpassword or exclude to force entry
database=mygotodb
```

Mysql would then open this file for each user account read the credentials and open the selected database.

Not sure on Windows, I upgraded from Windows because I needed the whole house not just the windows (aka Linux) a while back.

Comment: I believe that both answers are correct in some way. @Gary has pointed the solution that avoid us to set the schema every time we want to access our database and Devart give the solution to use it once.