# MYSQL set a default database

Tags: mysql

When I connect my MYSQL , I have to choose database to use everytime using :

```
use mysql_crashcourse;
```

I noticed the DATABASE() returns null when I check it right after I connect to MYSQL

```
mysql> SELECT DATABASE();
+------------+
| DATABASE() |
+------------+
| NULL       |
+------------+
```

My question is : how can I set a default MYSQL database ,so that I don't need to provide database info each time I connect or login to MYSQL ?

Comment: How do you connect o the database? Do you use `mysql` cli utility?

Comment: Check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12426320/how-do-i-set-the-default-schema-for-a-user-in-mysql

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you log-in directly from cli.
Create a client session on my.cnf and restart mysql service.

Note every `root` user logged from localhost will have the default database.

Example:

```
root@ergesttstsrv:~# cat /etc/mysql/my.cnf

[client]
host=localhost
user=root
password=
database=gesti

!includedir /etc/mysql/conf.d/
!includedir /etc/mysql/mysql.conf.d/

root@ergesttstsrv:~# service mysql restart

root@ergesttstsrv:~# mysql -u root -p
Enter password:
Reading table information for completion of table and column names
You can turn off this feature to get a quicker startup with -A

Welcome to the MySQL monitor.  Commands end with ; or \g.
Your MySQL connection id is 9
Server version: 8.0.25 MySQL Community Server - GPL

Copyright (c) 2000, 2021, Oracle and/or its affiliates.

Oracle is a registered trademark of Oracle Corporation and/or its
affiliates. Other names may be trademarks of their respective
owners.

Type 'help;' or '\h' for help. Type '\c' to clear the current input statement.

mysql> select database();
+------------+
| database() |
+------------+
| gesti      |
+------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

Answer (score -1):

If you do not select anything else in the query, the return value is null. If you want to get anything else, you can do for example:

```
 mysql> SELECT 1 IS NULL, 1 IS NOT "something";
```