# Grafana/Athena: How to reference datasource default value in Variable creation?

Tags: grafana, amazon-athena

I am building a Grafana dashboard using the Athena plugin. As part of this I wish to create a template variable that extracts all tables from the 'default' database set up in my datasource.

The following query works when I manually insert the name of the database:

```
SELECT DISTINCT table_name
FROM information_schema.tables 
WHERE table_schema ='nameofdatabase'
```

What I would, however, like to do is instead to use something ala below:

```
SELECT DISTINCT table_name
FROM information_schema.tables 
WHERE table_schema ='$default_datasource_database_value'
```

The idea is that my dashboard template variable cannot assume knowledge of the database value - that will generally be specified when setting up the datasource. I therefore want to refer to that default value in the Athena Query I'm using to generate this template variables drop down - but I am not able to find any documentation on how to reference the default database value from the datasource in my query.

Comment: AFAIK, you cannot access default database specified in data source configuration through variables. But I guess, something like this would be achievable inside database itself. For example, it can be done in MySQL with [`SELECT DATABASE()`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12426320). I guess Athena should have something like this too.